# Center four buttons in screen quarters

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to do something like this:

- Button 1 centered in the top left part of the screen
- Button 2 in the top right
- Button 3 in the bottom left
- and three or four buttons in the bottom right.

I'm new so I can't post a picture.
I tried different layouts but zero results.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: [SO] is not intended for "how do I do this" questions.  You should read the documentation available at http://developer.android.com and try something that is at least close, then post your layout here (although layout questions don't really belong here, it has become a common, if not inappropriate practice).  For more information consult the [faq]

Answer (score 3):

What you want is a RelativeLayout: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html

Something along the lines of:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <Button android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
    <Button android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
    <Button android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

From that you should be able to figure out the rest. I suggest reading up on RelativeLayout and its alignment parameters

EDIT- After you explained in the comments, try something like:

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_weight=".5">
        <LinearLayout android:layout_weight=".5">
            <Button android:layout_gravity="center" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_weight=".5">
            <Button android:layout_gravity="center" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout> 
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_weight=".5">
        <LinearLayout android:layout_weight=".5">
            <Button android:layout_gravity="center" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_weight=".5">
            <Button android:layout_gravity="center" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>        
</LinearLayout>
```

That will fill your screen with 4 equally-sized 'blocks' and have a button positioned directly in the center of each one.

Comment: I'm sorry but maybe I haven't made myself clear.
This puts the buttons in the corners, what I have in mind is to split the screen in four part and then put one button in the center of each part. Some thing like this http://i48.tinypic.com/24n2wt3.png

Comment: Updated my post with your comment. Sorry I didn't understand it initially

Comment: Thanks for the help but now lint says that "Nested weights are bad for performance". I used a TableLayout and now everyting works fine.

Comment: Yeah this doesn't work with the weighted linear layouts, Eclipse won't even compile it due t missing layout widths and heights.

Comment: Yeah, you need to add the widths/heights; set the width to fill_parent, and the heights to wrap_content or some dip value. I didn't include them as I thought you'd know to add them.

Answer (score 2):

After some work I made it with a TableLayout and some LinearLayouts.

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/TableLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:weightSum="4" >

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 2" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 3" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 4" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TableRow>
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a question posted like 5 min ago about this.

[How to properly distribute 4 buttons on an android layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11301319/how-to-properly-distribute-4-buttons-on-an-android-layout)

I don't want to be rude, but you should try harder.

Comment: you should flag as duplicate or create a comment rather than posting this as an answer