# Android Icon/buttons on corners

Tags: android, xml, layout

How would one go about creating a android screen layout like the following image :

[image].

I know the image I have used is of the home screen but I've see this layout being used in other apps, where the icons are on the corners.

Can anyone point me to an example or tutorial of how to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [RelativeLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) in Android docs.
It allows you specify for each view where it sits in regards to the parent layout, so you can get a child to align to top and left, and another to align to top and right.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Which led me to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11301319/how-to-properly-distribute-4-buttons-on-an-android-layout This was exactly what I was looking for.